# Machine Learning - How does a Single Perceptron learn?

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

How does a Perceptron learn?

To be more specific:
In university we had following exercise:
[Perceptron exercicse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZKE2.png)

The solution was kind of easy:
After the first Data-Point the weights were (0, -4, -3, 6) after the second Data-Point (1,-2, -5, 3) and so on. The algorithm we used to update the weights was (in Pseudocode):

If Act.Fct(f(x)) != y:

w_new = w_old + y * x

Else: Do nothing.

[Act.Fct = Activation Function]

What I dont understand at this point is: What is with the "Error-Function" (or Loss-Function)? Does a single layer Perceptron dont use this function to update the weights? Because in this algorith we havent calculatet any Error?

I know that in Neuronal-Networks (that are just a bunch of chained Perceptrons?) the Error-Function is used for backpropagation. Im just confused by this exercise, that it is not used for the single layer perceptron as well?

Comment: Welcome to SO; for such non-programming ML questions, please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.